# Can't use uint16_t in library

Tags: c++, c, compilation-errors, compiler

I wonder why the following minimal example sketch doesn't compile (`unknown type name 'uint16_t'`):

`sketch_does_not_compile.ino`:

```
#include "myheader.h"

void setup() {
  char a[]="hello world";
  uint16_t l=str_len(a);
  Serial.println(l);
}

void loop() {}
```

`myheader.c`:

```
uint16_t str_len(char* input_string) {
  uint16_t i=0;
  while (input_string[i++]!='\0');
  return i;
}
```

`myheader.h`:

```
#include "myheader.h"

uint16_t str_len(char* input_string);
```

Compilation fails with:

```
myheader.c: At top level:
myheader.c:3:1: error: unknown type name 'uint16_t'
 uint16_t str_len(char* input_string);
 ^
exit status 1
unknown type name 'uint16_t'
```

Using `uint16_t` in the .ino-file directly like in the sketch below compiles fine.

`sketch_compiles.ino`:

```
uint16_t str_len(char* input_string) {
  uint16_t i=0;
  while (input_string[i++]!='\0');
  return i;
}

void setup() {
  char a[]="hello world";
  uint16_t l=str_len(a);
  Serial.println(l);
}

void loop() {}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `#include <stdint.h>`

Comment: Why is the declaration of str_len() in the .c file and the implementation in the .h file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `#include <Arduino.h>` in your myheader.h will also include `<stdint.h>` and probably solve this.

The Arduino IDE automatically includes Arduino.h in the sketch itself, but apparently not for external stuff.